# How do I configure mysql the same way as sqlite in flask?

Tags: python, mysql, flask

This is the suggested configuration from the Doc for sqlite.
How would it be for mysql?

```
import sqlite3

import click
from flask import current_app, g
from flask.cli import with_appcontext


def get_db():
    if 'db' not in g:
        g.db = sqlite3.connect(
            current_app.config['DATABASE'],
            detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES
        )
        g.db.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

    return g.db


def close_db(e=None):
    db = g.pop('db', None)

    if db is not None:
        db.close()
def init_db():
    db = get_db()

    with current_app.open_resource('schema.sql') as f:
        db.executescript(f.read().decode('utf8'))
```

I would like to use the same command init-db to initialize the mysql

```
@click.command('init-db')
@with_appcontext
def init_db_command():
    """Clear the existing data and create new tables."""
    init_db()
    click.echo('Initialized the database.')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `ext.py`:

```
import pymysql

db = None

def get_db():
   global db
   if db is None:
       db = pymysql.connect("localhost","testuser","test123","TESTDB")
   return db
```

In other module, if you want to execute sql:

```
from ext import get_db
db = get_db()
db.cursor.execute(sql)
```

`db` is the singleton object. I suggest to use the sqlalchemy in Flask.

Comment: so I do not need to initialize the data base on the with the command init-db, do I?

Comment: yep. When you use it,  it will be got or inited.

Answer (score 0):

I would def. recommend you to use [Flask-SQLAlchemy](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-SQLAlchemy/), so you do not have to deal with low level SQL problems.

As a plus, you could use e.g. `SQLite` locally for testing, and `MySQL` or `Postgresql` in production, without changed your code (only your config).